# Union Two Tables and Overwrite Preexisting Rows

Tags: sql-server, union

I'm looking to union two tables together, but if there are any duplicate records where "Email" from Table 1 matches "Email" from Table 2, then data from Table 2 will be extracted. Is this function possible?

## Table 1

```
Name | Email   | Status
A    | a@a.com | 1
B    | b@b.com | 2
C    | c@c.com | 1
```

## Table 2

```
Name | Email   | Status
C    | c@c.com | 2
D    | d@d.com | 1
E    | e@e.com | 2
```

## Resulting Table

```
Name | Email   | Status
A    | a@a.com | 1
B    | b@b.com | 2
C    | c@c.com | 2
D    | d@d.com | 1
E    | e@e.com | 2
```

Comment: Have you tried anything that you can show us?

Comment: I didn't know where to begin. I was thinking of using a combination of Union, Update, and Join, but can't wrap my head around the syntax

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One approach to this problem is to do a `SELECT` against table1 with a `WHERE NOT IN` against table2 to filter the rows selected from table1 so that none of the rows that exist in table2 will be part of that result -- then that result can be UNION'd against table2.

Here's an example (TableA and TableB in my code):

```
declare @TableA as Table ( Name VarChar(20), Email VarChar(20), Status INT );
declare @TableB as Table ( Name VarChar(20), Email VarChar(20), Status INT );

insert into @TableA ( Name, Email, Status ) values
  ( 'A', 'a@a.com', 1 ),
  ( 'B', 'b@b.com', 2 ),
  ( 'C', 'c@c.com', 1 )

insert into @TableB ( Name, Email, Status ) values
  ( 'C', 'c@c.com', 2 ),
  ( 'D', 'd@d.com', 1 ),
  ( 'E', 'e@e.com', 2 )

SELECT * FROM @TableA WHERE Email NOT IN ( SELECT DISTINCT Email FROM @TableB )
UNION 
SELECT * FROM @TableB
```